# How to keep the random value remain same in a session variable in php

Tags: php

I am new in php and trying to solve a simple problem like create a random number and store it in session variable so that 
the value remain same for the entire session. I need to compare that value with user input from the same php page as below.

```
<?php 

    session_start();
    //get a random number and store it in session variable
    $_SESSION["random"] = rand(1,10); 
    $randomNumber = $_SESSION["random"];

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $input = $_POST['input'];

        if( $input > $randomNumber )
        {       
            //code
        }
        else if($input < $randomNumber)
        {
            //code
        }

    }       
?>


<html>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <label > Enter input to match:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="input" id="input" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the random number variable is set, and if not generate it, if so then don't:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["random"])) {
    $_SESSION["random"] = rand(1,10); 
}
$randomNumber = $_SESSION["random"];
```